# What statistical test can I use?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, t-test

I'm currently trying to test the effect of pH on the growth of three different types of grasses for my dissertation and didn't account for number of replicates being used (statistically dumb). Here is the data I have so far in Table 1. At the end there will be 9 pH's going up in increments of 0.5 (except the control). I am trying to test how the pH affects the weight in each of the treatments. The issue is that I have only 1 replicate. Is it even possible to analyse the data in anyway?

I don't have time left to produce more replicates given it has to be in for September.

```
pH  A. capillaris   F. rubra    L. perenne
3.5     0.28          13.06    11.95
3.5     0.28          4.45     7.22
3.5     0.56          3.89     12.50
3.5     0.28          12.22    12.78
3.5     0.56          11.94    10.00
3.5     0.28          7.22     5.83
3.5     0.56          3.89     12.50
```

Control ^

```
3.5     0.28          13.06    11.95
4.0     0.28          7.22     2.61
4.5     15.28         11.39    15.83
5.0     15.83         12.78    20.00
5.5     20.00         15.30    28.61
6.0     14.20         14.72    13.61
6.5     20.00         20.83    16.94
```

Ca(OH)2^

```
3.5     0.28          13.06    11.95
4.0     13.61         12.22    15.83
4.5     13.06         11.39    14.72
5.0     18.89         12.78    23.61
5.5     16.95         13.61    28.33
6.0     18.01         10.83    14.72
6.5     18.89         19.20    14.44
```

CaCO3 ^

Any advice is greatly welcomed

Cheers

Ryan

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't account for the number of replicates"? Are the values in the table aggregates or individual experiment results?

Comment: They're individual experiment results.

Comment: Can you type the numbers in? (Someone will be able to help you with the formatting.) This is hard to read.

Comment: If you copy and paste from your spreadsheet software into a plain-text editor like Notepad, you can then paste it into the post. If you select what you pasted and click the "**{ }**" button on the toolbar, it will format the text verbatim, in fixed-width font. Then you'll just have to adjust the spacing and it should look like a decent table. Or use [a tool that converts it into a plain-text-based format automatically](https://github.com/msprev/tabbed2md)

Comment: Can you explain what is the purpose/meaning of Ca(OH)2 and CaCO3 in your table? Are they 2 different substances used to adjust the pH (i.e. Treatments)?

Comment: Hello everyone thank's for your patience and interest in this, really appreciate it. The Table has been amended as suggested and the Ca(OH)2 and CaCO3 are different substances used to adjust the pH (Treatments)